# Continue statement in Python only goes back at start of the loop. How to make it go in any place of code?

Tags: python

I have this simple code:

```
var = 1
while var == 1 : 
   try:
        num = int(raw_input("Enter a number  :"))
   except ValueError:
        print "Thats not a number!"
        continue
   try:
        num2 = int(raw_input("Enter another number :"))
   except ValueError:
        print "Thats not a number!"
        continue
   print "Sum of previous 2 inputs:="+str(num+num2)
print "Good bye!"
```

Now first continue statement does the job, but the second one, not. Because it goes back at the top of loop, but I need it to go back where second exception was caught, so it would ask to enter second number again, not first number.

Any ideas?

Comment: You will need the Python [`goto` module](http://entrian.com/goto/). :)

Comment: You never change `var`, so the loop goes on forever. Is that what you intended?

Comment: @MarceloCantos yes, I intended that for now. I run .py file in terminal and test it, so I can quit program anytime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can factor out entering a number to a function – this spares you writing the same code twice:

```
def input_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(raw_input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print "That's not a valid integer!"

...
num = input_int("Please enter a number: ")
num2 = input_int("Please enter another number: ")
```

Comment: Thanks. I think thats a better solution. So there is no way to make continue go back to code where you want?:)

Comment: @oerp: Correct. there is no way to make `continue` go anywhere but back to the top of the loop. That is what it is designed to do.